# Botframework - Emulator error - GET to 'http://localhost:53378/v3/botstate/emulator/users/default-user' failed: [503] Service Unavailable

Tags: botframework

Bot framework emulator ends up with error to respond to user input.

**Code Snippet:**

```
var restify = require('restify');
var builder = require('botbuilder');

// Setup Restify Server
var server = restify.createServer();
server.listen(process.env.port || process.env.PORT || 3978, function({
console.log('%s listening to %s', server.name, server.url);
});

// Create chat connector for communicating with the Bot Framework 
//Service
var connector = new builder.ChatConnector({
appId: process.env.MICROSOFT_APP_ID,
appPassword: process.env.MICROSOFT_APP_PASSWORD
});

// Listen for messages from users
server.post('/api/messages', connector.listen());

// Receive messages from the user and respond by echoing each message 
// back (prefixed with 'You said:')
var bot = new builder.UniversalBot(connector, function (session) {
session.send("You said: %s", session.message.text);
});
```

**Error Log:**

```
Error: GET to 
'http://localhost:54596/v3/botstate/emulator/users/default-user' 
failed: [503] Service Unavailable
at Request._callback(/Users/xxx/ADE/BOT/hellobot/node_modules/
botbuilder/lib/bots/ChatConnector.js:559:46)
at Request.self.callback 
(/Users/xxx/ADE/BOT/hellobot/node_modules/
request/request.js:186:22)
at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
at Request.emit (events.js:214:7)
at Request.<anonymous> (/Users/xxx/ADE/BOT/hellobot/node_modules/
request/request.js:1163:10)
at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
at Request.emit (events.js:211:7)
at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> 
(/Users/xxx/ADE/BOT/hellobot/node_modules/
request/request.js:1085:12)
at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:313:30)
at emitNone (events.js:111:20)
```

Tried URL's http://localhost:3978/api/messages & http://127.0.0.1:3978/api/messages. Any idea what is causing the issue here?

Comment: Please add the code in the question details vs a link to an image.

Comment: Code Snippet screen added to the question.

Comment: Add the code to the question NOT as a link.

Comment: Added the code & error log to the question..Thanks @aaronR

Comment: This looks like a pretty standard echo bot so the problem must be either in your node environment or the emulator environment. I would suggest you one of these three options 1.- Create a new folder, download the node modules again, reinstall the emulator and try again. 2.- Create your bot in Azure, download the code using the Continuous Integration feature and test it against Azure Server or locally. 3.- Deploy your bot and test it remotely instead of locally.

Comment: What's your env? Could you provide node version, botbuilder version.